# (2.8) Img Texture Emitting thru Glass "Why is the glass black?"

Tags: glass, emission

Long time skimmer of blender, not well versed in any particular area.

I'm trying to use only the emitter itself as the light source, having it shine thru the fluid object. Each object renders out individually, but the water doesnt seem to recognize the emitter's existence.

I've tried switching the blend modes to no avail. Having this problem in both Eevee and cycles. Also tried futzing around with light path settings but v much out of my depth here.

Feel like this would've worked easier in blender render, but coming back after maybe a year or 2 away from blender, that doesn't appear to be an option anymore.

[image: here's my setup, the black square is a fluid object that is supposed to be refracting the emitted light below...]

[image: here's the fluid shader, super rudimentary, I'm not at all versed in nodes]

Comment: sorry nodes in the top pic is the emitting cube, nodes in the bottom pic is the glass element

Comment: have you enabled Render > Screen Space Reflections > Refraction and Material > Settings > Screen Space Refraction?